# Does stalling damage my car?

Tags: engine, stall, engine-theory

I sometimes stall my car, as I have a new one and the biting point is so high.

Anyway, someone told me stalling damages my car, but all it does is force the engine to a complete stop...

Does constant stalling damage my petrol car?

Comment: The answer to http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12752/why-does-an-engine-stall-manual-transmission?rq=1 is vry interesting and does have scenarios in which your car can apparently be damaged by stalling.

Comment: @Chris I disagree with the points mentioned in that thread by paulster about damage due to stalling, stalling a car now a then will not do any harm to the car, stalling everyday , every time you start the car for months will definitely damage but i dont think the OP is doing that,

Comment: @Anarach: Possibly. I don't know enough to be able to comment. Just saw the post and thought I'd share it. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.
Stalling the car will not damage your car , your car is designed to absorb the impact at least a hundred times.(Most of my family members learnt driving in my car and it has stalled half of its life and its working perfectly)

Stalling the car extremely frequently especially with load(passengers) can put additional stress on the transmission components but again its highly unlikely you will kill the car with stall.

Also stalling and starting the car frequently puts stress on your starter motor and the battery but those are the only things which can fail sooner than the car because of stalling but again , highly unlikely.

A point to note is that stalling can be extremely dangerous to you and your car when you are in the middle of the road, in traffic, you have the danger of another vehicle rear ending you and its very likely that it will happen since the other driver cannot counter the sudden decrease in your speed.

Comment: The last warning seems strange to me. I don't think I've ever come across anybody stalling a car at any significant speed. Its only ever when you are at low speeds and thus the engine is turning over too slowly that a stall happens. I would imagine that even in top gear you'd have to be going relatively slowly to stall your car... What sort of speeds are you thinking of in terms of stalling here?

Comment: @Chris I was talking about slow speeds only, not highway speeds.. example Rush hour city traffic.Also when you are pulling up to the highway from another road if you stall in the middle then you have the danger of getting rear ended.

Comment: Modern cars (at least in Europe) often automatically cut the engine after a few seconds when the car is stopped and the transmission is in neutral, to save fuel and exhaust emission pollution. The starter operates automatically when you depress the clutch pedal before selecting a gear. If the starter and battery are designed to handle "stalling the engine" every time you stop at a red light, a few more unintentional stalls are unlikely to harm anything.

Comment: @alephzero Though largely correct , you are ignoring one disadvantage of the "start stop" system. It puts strain on the starter motor. But in the real world no real damage can come as you say, I am pointing out to the OP the plausible (if at all any) damages that might occur.  Kindly refer to the question "http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/825/is-start-stop-technology-good-or-bad-for-my-car-alfa-mito"

Comment: The actual danger in stalling is while turning left while cars are flowing fast perpendicularly and waiting for an opening. If you enter the flow and stall then all you have is hope that they have enough time to brake.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing Yeah , Good point!