# How good is auto engine start stop feature?

Tags: engine, starting, engine-theory

Some new car models feature this auto engine stop when the car is in complete stop while you foot is on the pedal and auto restart the engine once you release it.

Is this "feature" any good?

I think it is good as in it saves fuel. I am not sure if it will cause damage to the engine or any other parts due to frequent start stop in town. At the end, do the goods outweigh the bads?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8D6N981zo8
fifth gear did a segment on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Start & Stop technology good or bad for my car? (Alfa MiTO)](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/825/is-start-stop-technology-good-or-bad-for-my-car-alfa-mito)

Answer (score 1):

Overall, I would think this would improve the life of the engine as it is running less.  This will cause the starter to work harder and wear out faster.  Since the engine was recently run, all of the parts will have a coating of oil.

I would think this system would wait until the engine is at operating temperate before starting the start/stop routine.  Otherwise, I would think starting/stopping on a cold engine could lead to more wear.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure, it seems like it would be harder on the ignition coil, but I'm not sure. They likely have tested this though...

Comment: There is concern over excessive wear due to increased starts, generally on the crankshaft and on the battery. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start-stop_system#Concerns)  (http://www.autocar.co.uk/car-news/new-cars/stop-start-long-term-impact-your-car-s-engine) (http://www.mazda.com/en/innovation/technology/env/)

Comment: Good points.  Thanks for the source!  I figured crankshaft wouldn't be too much of an issue since the engine had run within the past several minutes and should have a nice film of oil.  Still significantly better than a cold start or even a warm start after going shopping for 30 min.  Electric primer would help.  The I-stop is really cool, must use direct injection.  This would eliminate the heavy load on the battery and starter.  Not sure how it would increase the wear on a coil, do they receive increased voltage during cranking?  I know I can set this up on my 70 C20, but never have.